# Mounting device as mass storage instead of mtp

Tags: storage, udev, mtp, mass, kobo

So far I have not been able to get Calibre to detect my Kobo Clare 2E e-reader. The OS (ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) does detect the e-reader however. I can read and write it in Nautilus for example.

Now I have read somewhere that the problem is caused by mounting the e-reader as a MTP device.

I wondered how to mount the e-reader as a mass storage device instead of a MTP device. I have found this: https://superuser.com/questions/1206664 but for the time being to no avail.

I really do not know which file with extension .rules I should change.
So my question is: how can I force a device to be mounted as a mass storage device instead of a MTP device?

Thanks in advance!

According to https://superuser.com/questions/1206664 I created a file 90-myrules.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d. Rebooted and unplugged/replugged the e-reader.